# I want to add a validation to restrict input value, the value has to be less than 5 if it greator that 5 it should show error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, frontend

[I am reactjs function, need to add validation to the  input value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBCjG.jpg)

```
<Form.Group size="sm" as={Row} controlId="formBasicEmail">
  <Form.Label>Amount</Form.Label>
  <Form.Control 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Enter Amount" 
    value={hospitalId}
    onChange={e => sethospitalId(e.target.value)} />
  <Form.Text className="text-muted">
    Please input your desired amount.
  </Form.Text>
</Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways and frameworks to do validation in Javascript/React. I personally prefer `Yup`, which is pretty easy and straightforward for simple cases but also let's you handle more complicated scenarios. It let's you validate your input with a schema you define beforehand, like this:

```
let validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
  hospitalId: yup.number().max(5),
});
```

For more info, take a look at their [GitHub page](https://github.com/jquense/yup).